# TypeError for "offsetParent" property of d3 svg selection in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, svg

The following code works in Chrome 44 but not in Firefox 40:

```
var width = 460, height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

svg.append("text").text("Offset = " + svg.property("offsetParent").offsetTop)
```

Firefox throws a `TypeError: svg.property(...) is undefined` exception.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cnguvfh/) of the code.

Is this a bug, i.e., should I report it?
Is there any alternative to get the parent offset in Firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure report it, but as a Chrome bug, not a Firefox one. [offsetParent](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-htmlelement-interface) is an HTML element property only. It should return undefined when called on an SVG element which is precisely what Firefox does.

You could try [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) the left/top values of that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the end I actually needed the `property("offsetParent").offsetTop` of the div surrounding the svg (this is actually what Chrome returns in my example) instead of the `getBoundingClientRect.top`. Why they don't return the same value puzzles me...

Comment: Strange but true! Any idea why client rect/scroll stuff was added to `Element` but the offset stuff was only added to `HTMLElement`? Odd that I can e.g. `position: absolute` an `<svg>` relative to its offset parent via CSS, but otoh, can't tell which parent that is via JS. (The spec does make a distinction between "CSS Layout Box" — used by the offset stuff — and "SVG Layout Box" but its unclear why they couldn't just use the combined "layout box" term instead.)